# Median in a distribution function

Tags: probability, median

Can I get some help finding the median of the following distribution function? Please.

$F(x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             0 &   if  & x < 1 \\
             \\ \frac{x-1}{5} &  if & 1 \leq x < 3 \\
             \\ \frac{x+1}{5} &  if  & 3 \leq x < 4 \\
             \\ 1 & if & 4 \leq x
             \end{array}
   \right. $
Where $X$ is a random variable

Comment: I tried graphing the function, and try to see visually the median, but I couldn't see it

Comment: Follow the definitin: $F(m)=0.5$.